# javascript function syntax validator

Tags: javascript, validation, syntax

How can I validate a javascript function in my code? The purpose is , I am developing a java application in which user can add their custom javascript functions. These function will be stored in DB and execute later. I have seen some online tool for the same. but not found any code that can be integrated in to my app.

Comment: You have the code to run them already, right? If code is not valid, the runner will raise errors or otherwise misbehave. So you can use that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that sounds like a terrible idea. What about security considerations? I'd suggest only allowing a safe subset of javascript

Comment: Are the users supposed to add javascript code for documentation only or this js is supposed to be executed somehow?

Comment: @Aaron: yeah, yeah, but then again, running user code is a terrible idea itself. He has to put protections/sandboxing/whatever in place. And if that is done, then this method of validation is acceptable, I would say.

Comment: We'd need to know who would be able to input js code, and who would run it later. If it's a web-accessible service, that any user can input js code and any other user run it in its own browser later, just making sure that the code runs isn't enough. If the code is run server-side (node.js?) then I agree using proper sandboxing should be enough